# Android wifi says "Connected, no internet" but internet works just fine

Tags: wi-fi, bugs, dns

This is a strange thing that started happening with the wifi network at my work.  Android devices connected to the network say "Connected, no internet" however the internet works perfectly well.  This has happened to devices running android 6 and 7.  This is a small business in the US and theres no proxy or captive portal that is blocking any DNS.  Windows and Ubuntu laptops connect and say everything is fine, seems to be something Android specific.

Does anyone know how exactly Android determines weather a network has internet access?  This seems like the solution will end up in the router configuration, but knowing what could cause Android to behave this way would be helpful.  What steps could one take to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Would be helpful to know what devices you're using that give this issue. If the devices are all from one manufacturer and it works fine when you connect with a different manufacturer's device that would narrow things down. But if it happens to devices with multiple manufacturers I would guess something to do with your router configuration but this is a really odd issue.

Comment: I see this sometimes at work; I tend to ignore it. We use Umbrella Solutions to capture illicit web traffic.

Comment: Another point to narrow it down: Do all your Google services work fine? Have you e.g. tried to use Playstore, GMail etc? I'm not 100% sure, but AFAIR the detection uses some Google IP and sees if that can be reached.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this seems likely to be a problem connecting to Google servers (captive portal server) **not the browser configured captive portal login** you seem to be refering to in your post.

(Sometime since Lollipop (5.1+)) When connected to networks (especially Wi-Fi networks), android system  checks if there is an active internet connection by perfoming checks on certain pre-defined URLs belonging to Google servers. If it fails, there'll be an exclamation mark on the Wi-Fi signal icon and a  “Connected, no internet” notification is shown **(even though you can access other websites and the internet is up an running)** so it may be a temporary problem with connectivity to that specific URL:

> Android tries to reach a file named `generate_204` on one of the Google
>   servers and if there is no positive response, it means that there is
>   no connection to the internet, and notification is generated also, the detection url differs between
>   different Android versions.

- `clients3.google.com/generate_204 check (kitkat)`
- `connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204 (marshmallow)`

It seems that google has changed the captive portal 
detection on recent  versions of android e.g oreo.

looks like google now checks for both a `generate_204` on both 
`connectivitycheck.gstatic.com` and a `gen_204` on 
`www.google.com`.

Again is a problem on its own esp in regions where access to google services is blocked. This [**answer**](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/186995/209414) however explains well how to bypass such and you make take a look at it.

A chunk of information has been extracted from [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187768/209414) discussion.

Based on this you have some options to bypass this:

1. **Changing captive portal server**

   - Install a terminal app alternatively these  commands can also be run via the `adb shell`.
   - Open the terminal app and run `su`.
   - Run `settings get global captive_portal_server`. This will show the current captive portal server. A "null" reply is usually the default.
   - Run `settings put global captive_portal_server YOUR_SERVER_ADDRESS`. You can  add google.com as the captive portal server, `i.e settings put global captive_portal_server google.com`.
   - Run `exit` once to exit from su, then exit one more time to close the terminal.
   - Reboot the Android device. Will not work without a reboot.

---

2. **Disabling captive portal**

> - Since the culprit is a method `isCaptivePortal()` which access `clients3.google.com/generate_204` to test if a connection is deemed
>     "usable". The page, as its name suggest, is designed to always return
>     a `HTTP 204` status code. Based on this you have a couple options:

i. Kill `isCaptivePortal()` completely

- with [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) set, run `adb shell su -c "settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0"` (Android 7.1+)
  or using `adb shell su -c "settings put global captive_portal_mode 0"`

Note:  *The down side is that isCaptivePortal() is actually useful to detect for example when a WiFi network requires login. If the request to the 204 page gets redirected to a login page (not a 204), the system will understand and display the exclamation mark as intended.*

ii. Change the target of `isCaptivePortal()`

- another workaround is replacing the Google host with a host that is accessible within the specific region. This host should also be returning `204` every time `/generate_204` is accessed.

  i.e `adb shell su -c "settings put global captive_portal_server {alternate_host} "`

---

3. **Using hosts**

   - You can edit `hosts` to block the captive portal detection url thus bypassing the sending of the requests to captive portal server.

---

**Why Linux and Windows connect with no issues?**

As you mentioned in your post that this seems to be Android specific, indeed the above discussion highlights that. The reason is that for those devices (Linux and Windows) the mechanism of connection is completely different.

These devices won't need to connect to Google servers to first detect if an internet is active.

Comment: Using the command `adb shell su -c "settings put global captive_portal_mode 0"` worked for me without a reboot (Android 8.1, MIUI 10). Just as a little side note for others.

Answer (score 0):

Check time and date on your android device. In https era is very important to have date and time in sync with reality.
I had this issue today with my TV and it was a few years late. :)