# Captive Portal parameters

Tags: networking, privacy, captive-portal

There are [several captive portal parameters](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#8795) one could apply to an Android device via `settings put global` – the most famous probably being

```
settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

to completely turn off captive portal check (for Android < 8). Can someone explain how to use the others – e.g. to define a "custom captive portal server for tin-foils"? For example, one cannot simply do a

```
settings put global captive_portal_server example.com
```

as that would, in most cases, cause captive portal check to permanently fail (background: doing so, portal check would construct an URL `http://example.com/generate_204` and check against that, expecting a specific response).

So apart from simply deactivating captive portal check altogether (which might, as I've read, lead to other issues like not being redirected to the correct portal in some cases), what else can one do to enhance privacy in this context?

Examples (if I got them right):

- `captive_portal_mode` (Android 8+?):

  - `0`: Don't attempt to detect captive portals
  - `1`: Prompt the user to sign in
  - `2`: Immediately disconnect from the network and do not reconnect to that network in the future
- `captive_portal_detection_enabled` (Android <8?):

  - `0`: Completely disable captive portal checks
  - `1`: Enable it (default)

While these examples are pretty much straight-forward: How to use the other parameters?

Comment: See also: [Very frequent Wifi disconnection while being in China](/questions/110789), [How to force android 6 to automatically connect to a network without internet access?](/questions/176993), [How to disable captive portal detection?](/questions/100657), [Connect to Wifi network even if it doesn't have internet access](/questions/66964), [How can I automatically re-connect to a WiFi network?](/questions/220414), [android 6.0.1 force wifi connection with no internet access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218510)

Comment: @MichaelAltfield instead of dropping a bunch of links, might to explain what they are for and why one should visit them? I've checked a few of them, but they don't seem to bring anything new here (in fact, some are even older).

Comment: @ Izzy the links allow the relevant questions to appear in the "linked" sidebar, to help SEO and people find the answer to their question.

Comment: I see that – but still some context would have helped (especially as you put each link into a separate comment; wouldn't the linked-box also be filled if you combined them into one or two? Just tested that for you, works fine – and isn't it also better readable this way? ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Configuring captive portal behaviour**

- `captive_portal_detection_enabled` (<= Android 7.1.1)

  - works as described in question body
- `captive_portal_mode` (>= Android 7.1.2)

  - works as described in question body

**Setting captive portal URL(s)**

- `captive_portal_server` (<= Android 6.0.1)

  - The server that holds a `generate_204` page, used to internally craft a URL for captive portal detection (`new URL("http", mServer, "/generate_204");` – obsolete as of Android 7.0, see below)
- `captive_portal_use_https` (>= Android 7.0)

  - `0`: Don't use HTTPS for network validation
  - `1`: Use HTTPS (default)
- `captive_portal_http_url` (>= Android 7.0)

  - The URL used for HTTP captive portal detection - use in pair with `captive_portal_use_https` (set to `0`)
  - >= Android 7.1.1: OS no longer appends `generate_204` to URL automatically, giving input URL some flexibility
- `captive_portal_https_url` (>= Android 7.0)

  - The URL used for HTTPS captive portal detection - use in pair with `captive_portal_use_https` (set to `1`)
  - >= Android 7.1.1: OS no longer appends `generate_204` to URL automatically

**Requirement for the URL to be used**

A HTTP 204 response code ("no content") from the server is used for validation, no extra content needed: take the default detection URL for example, `curl clients3.google.com/generate_204` returns empty, and inspecting HTTP response by adding `--write-out %{http_code}` returns `204`.'

**A small list of usable captive portal server URLs in mainland China** (personally tested)

> https://captive.v2ex.co/generate_204 (hosted by v2ex.com)
>
> https://connect.rom.miui.com/generate_204 (hosted by Xiaomi, used by default on MIUI)
>
> https://noisyfox.cn/generate_204 (hosted by noisyfox.cn)
>
> https://www.google.cn/generate_204 & https://developers.google.cn/generate_204 (hosted by Google)
>
> https://www.qualcomm.cn/generate_204 (hosted by Qualcomm)

**Further notes**

The source also mentions parameters `captive_portal_user_agent`, `captive_portal_fallback_url` and `captive_portal_other_fallback_urls`:

- `captive_portal_fallback_url` (>= Android 7.1.1) obviously is supposed to hold a single URL, while
- `captive_portal_other_fallback_urls` holds multiple further URLs (comma separated list, so the URLs might not contain any comma).

But I personally conducted tests on Android 8.0.0, and both fallback parameters don't work. Assuming they're declarations without an implementation for now.

Some examples of [captive portal settings of Android in China](https://gist.github.com/tonyseek/bc5b72197ddb15418c61406061720186) show the use of some of the above settings:

```
adb shell settings put global captive_portal_http_url http://www.google.cn/generate_204
adb shell settings put global captive_portal_https_url https://www.google.cn/generate_204
adb shell settings put global captive_portal_fallback_url http://www.google.cn/generate_204
adb shell settings put global captive_portal_other_fallback_urls http://www.qualcomm.cn/generate_204
```

Knowing that, "tin foils" even could set up their own verification service. With Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /generate_204$
RewriteRule $ / [R=204,L]
```

or with Nginx:

```
location / generate_204 { return 204 ; }
```

**References**

[1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#8795), [2](https://www.noisyfox.io/android-captive-portal.html) (Chinese), [3](https://www.v2ex.com/t/347803) (Chinese)

Comment: [Related post](/a/114041/16575) – and at least with MM, the following code is used: `new URL("http", mServer, "/generate_204");` (with `mServer` being initialized by `captive_portal_server` if set) – so this should just be the server name (or IP) there (which was most likely one of the reasons it failed for me on a MM device). Not sure when it changed then – but from what you write probably with N. For the 204, I've [found this](https://www.koozai.com/blog/analytics/server-response-codes-and-what-they-mean/#204) – so it seems I assumed correctly: just the 204 code, no content.

Comment: @Izzy Unfortunately the 2 fallback options don't seem to work. Using the default `captive_portal_https_url` and putting a reachable URL in `captive_portal_fallback_url` doesn't eliminate the cross mark, and same goes for putting in `captive_portal_other_fallback_urls` - Setting `captive_portal_https_url` straight is the only way out. Note that the tests are conducted under LTE instead of WiFi, because for some reason my school WiFi would always direct me to the captive portal even if I set a completely invalid URL.

Comment: Those fallback parameters might have been introduced with Oreo (note we've looked at Oreo code to find them). Guess you've checked on Nougat, right? // Good idea to include a little server list. AFAIK there also was `g.cn` available ;)

Comment: @Izzy Oh yeah, didn't realize that, I haven't flashed any of my devices with LOS15 yet. Might be worthy of checking out, and if it works I'll update and ping you to clean up the comments. Also, the HTTPS cert of g.cn is said to have expired in mainland, so it's no longer usable for HTTPS. // But wait... The 7.1.2 source code does also contain reference to `captive_portal_fallback_url`.

Comment: Like with many new features, references sometimes turn up before the feature is complete. And the file referenced mainly defines the constants, not the functionality, right?

Comment: @Izzy Tested on a LOS15 device, fallback options still don't do a thing. Guess this seals it for now.

Comment: Some details for Oreo [here](https://www.kuketz-blog.de/geloest-deaktivierung-captive-portal-check-unter-android-oreo/); basically "how to disable captive portal check". Interestingly, the parameter `captive_portal_server` which you commented as "<= MM" comes into play here again.