# WiFi says connected without internet, but works fine

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, 7.1-nougat, 9.0-pie

I am connected to a school WiFi network and I am able to access webpages and my apps work fine, but Android says I am connected but have no network. The issue is that Android defaults to mobile data when it claims it isn't connected, which costs me money. I know that I am connected and have internet access, even when mobile data is turned off.

As of now, I have just been turning mobile data off in order to keep Android from defaulting to mobile data on that network.

I'm on a Pixel XL on Android 9.0 pie. The issue has existed since I got the phone (it was on 7.1 Nougat at that time)

Comment: Don't know if this is helpful but, there was a similar post addressing the same issue: [Android wifi says “Connected, no internet” but internet works just fine](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/170387/209414)

Comment: Are you using a firewall app like AFWall?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by rebooting the router. You can also just restart the gateway.