# Cannot logon to a "captive portal" wi-fi network

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal

I am unable to connect to any wi-fi networks that require a login through what I assume is captive portal. This worked fine for perhaps a year but has stopped working recently. I am running Android 8.1.0 on a Nokia 6.

I get the following response after attempting go to the login:

[image]

Comment: That looks like a captive portal detection url (i.e `connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204`, try some solutions [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/187768/209414) to resolve